# Correct sparse information

Tags: r

I've a survey where the answers to a question supposedly to be in one column is actually sparse in 50 columns. I'd like to consolidate the answer distributed on those columns in one sole column. How could I make it?

```
mySurvey <- data.frame(Q1 = c("A", "", "", ""),
                     Q2 = c("", "B", "", ""),
                     Q3 = c("", "", "C", ""),
                     Q4 = c("", "", "", "D") )

> mySurvey
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  A         
2     B      
3        C   
4           D
```

**Desired result** One column with the sparse answer:

```
mySurvey
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q
1  A          A
2     B       B
3        C    C
4           D D
```

Comment: Are they all along the diagonal? Maybe `data.frame(Q = diag(as.matrix(mySurvey)), row.names = names(mySurvey))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `apply` function to "loop" over each row and only keep values of the row that are not the empty string.

```
mySurvey <- data.frame(Q1 = c("A", "", "", ""),
                       Q2 = c("", "B", "", ""),
                       Q3 = c("", "", "C", ""),
                       Q4 = c("", "", "", "D") )
mySurvey <- cbind(mySurvey, Q=apply(mySurvey, 1, function(x) x[x!=""]))
```

Output:

```
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q
1  A          A
2     B       B
3        C    C
4           D D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unlist the data frame to get the answers:

```
data.frame( 
  Questions = names(mySurvey), 
  Answers = unlist(mySurvey[mySurvey != ""])
)

#   Questions Answers
# 1        Q1       A
# 2        Q2       B
# 3        Q3       C
# 4        Q4       D
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `max.col` to create a column index, `cbind` with row index, extract the elements

```
mySurvey$Q <-mySurvey[cbind(1:nrow(mySurvey),max.col(mySurvey!=''))]
mySurvey
#  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q
#1  A          A
#2     B       B
#3        C    C
#4           D D
```

Or another option is `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get row/column index

```
mySurvey$Q <- mySurvey[which(mySurvey!='',arr.ind=TRUE)]
```